# JavaScript split string with .match(regex)

Tags: javascript, regex, split

From the Mozilla Developer Network for function `split()`:

> The split() method returns the new array.
>
> When found, separator is removed from the string and the substrings
>   are returned in an array. If separator is not found or is omitted, the
>   array contains one element consisting of the entire string. If
>   separator is an empty string, str is converted to an array of
>   characters.
>
> If separator is a regular expression that contains capturing
>   parentheses, then each time separator is matched, the results
>   (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are
>   spliced into the output array. However, not all browsers support this
>   capability.

Take the following example:

```
var string1 = 'one, two, three, four';
var splitString1 = string1.split(', ');
console.log(splitString1); // Outputs ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

This is a really clean approach. I tried the same with a regular expression and a somewhat different string:

```
var string2 = 'one split two split three split four';
var splitString2 = string2.split(/\ split\ /);
console.log(splitString2); // Outputs ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

This works just as well as the first example. In the following example, I have altered the string once more, with 3 different delimiters:

```
var string3 = 'one split two splat three splot four';
var splitString3 = string3.split(/\ split\ |\ splat\ |\ splot\ /);
console.log(splitString3); // Outputs ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

However, the regular expression gets relatively messy right now. I can group the different delimiters, however the result will then include these delimiters:

```
var string4 = 'one split two splat three splot four';
var splitString4 = string4.split(/\ (split|splat|splot)\ /);
console.log(splitString4); // Outputs ["one", "split", "two", "splat", "three", "splot", "four"]
```

So I tried removing the spaces from the regular expression while leaving the group, without much avail:

```
var string5 = 'one split two splat three splot four';
var splitString5 = string5.split(/(split|splat|splot)/);
console.log(splitString5);
```

Although, when I remove the parentheses in the regular expression, the delimiter is gone in the split string:

```
var string6 = 'one split two splat three splot four';
var splitString6 = string6.split(/split|splat|splot/);
console.log(splitString6); // Outputs ["one ", " two ", " three ", " four"]
```

An alternative would be to use `match()` to filter out the delimiters, except I don't really understand how reverse lookaheads work:

```
var string7 = 'one split two split three split four';
var splitString7 = string7.match(/((?!split).)*/g);
console.log(splitString7); // Outputs ["one ", "", "plit two ", "", "plit three ", "", "plit four", ""]
```

It doesn't match the whole word to begin with. And to be honest, I don't even know what's going on here exactly.

---

How do I properly split a string using regular expressions without having the delimiter in my result?

Comment: Perhaps `string5.split(/\s?(split|splat|splot)\s?/)`

Comment: As you figured out, you don't need (nor want) the group. So to include the spaces as delimiters, you could enter them in each alternation - `/ split | splat | splot /`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use a **non-capturing group** as split regex. By using non-capturing group, split matches will not be included in resulting array.

```js
var string4 = 'one split two splat three splot four';
var splitString4 = string4.split(/\s+(?:split|splat|splot)\s+/);
console.log(splitString4);
```

```
// Output => ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

Comment: hi @anubhava i am curious to know how to split  following string only if breaking point like 1. ,2. etc comes in between string for example string = "1. Download directly via Steam before 29 Sep.
2. Enjoy your new Steam game!" .

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your problem properly

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `match` you can write it like

```
'one split two split three split four'.match(/(\b(?!split\b)[^ $]+\b)/g)
["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

**What it does?**

- `\b` Matches a word boundary
- `(?!split\b)` Negative look ahead, check if the word is *not* `split`
- `[^ $]+` Matches anything other than space or `$`, end of string. This pattern will match a word, the look ahead ensures that what it matches is not `split`.
- `\b` Matches the word end.